# TSLint mentions problems with generic Handler

Tags: typescript, tslint

I use an event dispatcher to register and fire events within classes in TypeScript. The code works fine. For a better code quality I use TSLint, which is unhappy about a the way I declare the handler, but I do not understand the description.

The code fragment:

```
export type Handler<E> = (event: E) => void;

export class EventDispatcher<E> {
    private handlers: Handler<E>[] = [];

    public fire(event: E) {
        for (const h of this.handlers) {
            h(event);
        }
    }

    public register(handler: Handler<E>) {
        this.handlers.push(handler);
    }
}
```

TSLint is unhappy about line 4 in the code, specifically about `Handler<E>[]`. The message is:

> [tslint] Array type using 'T[]' is forbidden for non-simple types. Use
>   'Array' instead. (array-type) [tslint] Array type using 'T[]' is
>   forbidden for non-simple types. Use 'Array' instead. type
>   Handler = (event: E) => void

I do not fully understand what TSLint wants me to do. Why is `T` forbidden? What is meant with a non-simple type? It also sais that I should use an array instead, but `Handler<E>[]` already is an array. So where is there problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays of non-simple types are hard to read. Consider a variable defined as:

```
let foo: { prop1: string; prop2: string;}[]
```

It might be easy to miss the `[]` at the end with such a log item type. Even in your case since the item of the array is a generic type it might be easy to miss the `[]` at the end after the `<..>`.

The linter wants you to use the long form of array, the generic `Array<T>` type. The two forms are perfectly equivalent, so it's just a readability issue. In your case, this should work

```
export type Handler<E> = (event: E) => void;

export class EventDispatcher<E> {
    private handlers: Array<Handler<E>> = [];

    public fire(event: E) {
        for (const h of this.handlers) {
            h(event);
        }
    }

    public register(handler: Handler<E>) {
        this.handlers.push(handler);
    }
}
```